How to concatenate multiple cuts of a video while also hardcoding embedded subs (ffmpeg)
I have a command that cuts different parts of the same video and concatenates them together, both the video and the audio tracks, into an mp4 file:
ffmpeg `
    -ss 15:23.465 -to 15:35.561 -i episode.mkv `
    -ss 16:06.258 -to 16:21.565 -i episode.mkv `
    -ss 16:57.643 -to 19:31.213 -i episode.mkv `
    -filter_complex '[0:v][0:a:1][1:v][1:a:1][2:v][2:a:1]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]' `
    -map '[outv]' `
    -map '[outa]' `
    -c:v libx264 -b:v 4500k `
    -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ac 2 -f mp4 `
    out.mp4

But I also would like to burn one of the embedded srt subtitle tracks on the final video in the same command. I've tried changing the -filter_complex argument like follows:
 -filter_complex '[0:v]subtitles=episode.mkv:si=1[v0];[1:v]subtitles=episode.mkv:si=1[v1];[2:v]subtitles=episode.mkv:si=1[v2];[v0][0:a:1][v1][1:a:1][v2][2:a:1]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]' `

But the subs are not properly timed. The first cut starts at ~15min, but the sub shown is from 0min, the second cut starts at 16, but the subs also start from 0min, etc.
How should I write this command to get the desired output?

This worked:
ffmpeg -i episode.mkv -filter_complex `
 "[0:v]subtitles=episode.mkv:si=1:force_style='Fontsize=24,Fontname=SegoeUI.ttf,ScaleX=0.8'[vs1]; `
  [0:v]subtitles=episode.mkv:si=1:force_style='Fontsize=24,Fontname=SegoeUI.ttf,ScaleX=0.8'[vs2]; `
  [0:v]subtitles=episode.mkv:si=1:force_style='Fontsize=24,Fontname=SegoeUI.ttf,ScaleX=0.8'[vs3]; `
  [vs1]trim=start='00\:15\:23.465':end='00\:15\:35.561',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; `
  [0:a:1]atrim=start='00\:15\:23.465':end='00\:15\:35.561',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; `
  [vs2]trim=start='00\:16\:06.258':end='00\:16\:21.565',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; `
  [0:a:1]atrim=start='00\:16\:06.258':end='00\:16\:21.565',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; `
  [vs3]trim=start='00\:16\:57.643':end='00\:19\:31.213',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; `
  [0:a:1]atrim=start='00\:16\:57.643':end='00\:19\:31.213',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3]; `
  [v1][v2][v3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[outv]; `
  [a1][a2][a3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" `
  -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" `
  -c:v libx264 -b:v 1M `
  -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ac 2 -y `
  out2.mp4

I had to set a burning for each cut (vs1, vs2 and vs3).
